# Program search in google. Can't find parameter of region

Tags: google-search

I have problem. I writing a program for search site position in google. It works like this:

Make search from url string. Then parse results of html page and find site position. But I can't find where to dispose parameter of region. Maby it inside url string parameters. Maby that must send inside cookies to server. Maby something more. I use for search    google.ru site.

Comment: Site position?? Do you mean the location of the ip-address of the request? This is in the header.

Comment: I mean I need to set region for search in google search. I need to make it from progrram way. Not from interface.

Answer (score 3):

The query string parameter for "Find pages published in a particular region" is cr, and the possible values for this parameter appear to be the string "country" followed by the [2-letter ISO country code](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2).  For example, to search for pages published in the United States, add `&cr=countryUS` to your query string; to search for pages published in Russia, add `&cr=countryRU` to your query string.

For more exploring, experiment with the Google [Advanced Search](https://www.google.com/advanced_search) page or [Advanced Search (in Russian)](http://www.google.ru/advanced_search)--type in some search parameters--and watch your browser's address bar to see the URL (and its query string) that is constructed for you.

**Post script**

Other query string parameters that you might find useful are

1. language: to restrict to Russian-language pages, add `&lr=lang_ru`
2. site/domain: to restrict to pages in the .ru domain, add `&as_sitesearch=.ru`

**More on the &cr parameter**

Although the parameter is labeled "region," it is limited to searching for pages that originate in a particular country.  It cannot be used for searching for pages from particular territories, states, provinces, or the various sorts of subdivisions in a country like Russia.  I suspect that Google uses the word "region" to avoid political disagreements where the status of a place is in dispute.  For more information, see [Google's documentation of the XML API](https://developers.google.com/custom-search/docs/xml_results?hl=en#crsp) (the documentation says that it is applicable only to Google Site Search customers, but I think that it applies in your case).

Comment: I understand. It's work when i use like region parameter a country id. But how I can use like region parameter diffrent areas inside Russia ? I carefully trying to construct this parameter from that references https://www.google.com/advanced_search  http://www.google.ru/advanced_search . I find another reference http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-2:RU . I trying to put country code from this reference in cr parameter. But it doesn't work. Html page is the same.